# Does user's iOS version limit their ability to install an app from the app store, is there a way to make it universal?

Tags: ios

I recently got an app on the app store and some of my friends who are still running iOS 11 indicated they were not able to install it.  Is it correct to assume that the iOS version limits their ability to install and there are steps I missed for supporting older iOS versions?  For example, is there some setting I should tweak when uploading xCode -> app store connect that would make it available to previous iOS versions?  Is there something I should do when submitting app store connect -> app store that would enable older iOS versions?

With iOS 13 coming out I would appreciate any insight on this topic, phrases I should google, or links to tutorials/docs as I suspect my current issue supporting users with 11/12 will quickly be an 11/12/13 issue.

Comment: Daniel what did you use to create your app? In Xcode you specify the minimum iOS version in the project settings. You need to build and test your app for all supported versions.

Comment: It all depends on the Deployment Target setting of your project.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the answer, it solved my issue. Is the proper thing to leave my question here or should I delete it since its a dupe?  I don't want to get down voted.